# Suddenly archiving in org-mode very slow

Tags: org-mode

In my tasks.org I use `C-c S-$` in order to archive single tasks and I also have a function (I don't remember where I got the idea from) to automate that within a tree. It used to be slow the first time I used `C-c` S-$` or at the beginning of using that function. But suddenly this process has become ultra slow. It means that archiving 300 characters takes minutes, literally. And it even leads to zoom sessions being interrupted visually (I can still participate via audio, but the video stream just freezes). I am on linux openSuse leap 15.3 gnome x-org and using emacs org-mode 25.3. I can't seem to find the answer to that, so I'm wondering if anyone else already solved a similar problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you change something at your end? Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: You might want to profile the Org mode code: do `C-h i g (elisp)profiling` to find out more.